# Google Sheet Data Connectors Updates Collapse

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

I have a Google Sheet that is connected to BigQuery. Every time I add a new field to the query that's connected builds the sheet it updates the extract and crashes the pivot table based on it.
Any idea on how to prevent it from happening?

I've tried to add new fields following the last column. I would prefer finding a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it doesn't seem like there's a provided solution in Google Sheets.
Pivot tables rely on ranges, and need space to work.
The ideal "workaroundy" approach to prevent pivot tables from crashing in my opinion is:

1. Have the connector's extracted data in 1 sheet
2. Have the pivot table referring that extracted data, potentially with more columns selected in the range than the actual columns that exist. For example, if your current data is on columns A:C, edit the pivot table range to be A:AA for future columns. The pivot table should be in a different sheet.
3. Any column you add after the pivot table is created should be added as the right-most column to prevent new order of columns. Although Google Sheets let's you select the column in the pivot table by name, it actually seems to be using the column index behind the scenes.